# Adding new object to another without wrapper

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm importing some json from another files using es6 but when i try to gather them inside of another json object they added with variable name as array name.

element1.js

```
module.exports = {
   'element1': { foo: 'bar' }
}
```

element2.js

```
module.exports = {
   'element2': { foo: 'bar' }
}
```

when i run this code below;

```
import elementVar1 from './element1.js'
import elementVar2 from './element2.js'

const list = { elementVar1, elementVar2 }
```

list returns as below;

```
{
  elementVar1: {
     element1: {
        foo: 'bar'
     }
  },
  elementVar2: {
     element2: {
        foo: 'bar'
     }
  }
}
```

my aim is process these elements without any wrapper like this;

```
{
   element1: {
      foo: 'bar'
   },
   element2: {
      foo: 'bar'
   }
}
```

basicly i want to concat them

Comment: No need to wrap it in `{}` just use `const list = elementVar`, Or why not just `import list from './element.js'`

Comment: There is no JSON in your example, only JavaScript objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do...

```
import elementVar from './element.js'

const list = elementVar;
```

**EDIT**

Based on changed question... the solution will be as follows:

```
import elementVar1 from './element1.js'
import elementVar2 from './element2.js'

const list = Object.assign({}, elementVar1, elementVar2);
```

Comment: You should add that this will copy the reference. `const list = Object.assign({}, elementVar);` to create a shallow clone

Comment: Because i don't want to do this process for only one element. I'm gonna concat multiple elements. i edited the question.

Comment: @BarışTuna Please see my edited response.

Comment: thank you very much @SantanuBiswas this is what i wanted to do